# How to handle incoming message to create a conversation in Twilio conversation api?

Tags: reactjs, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-conversations

I have a chat app [link](http://3.132.76.65/react-chat-app/build/) now I need to add a SMS participant.

My use case is say you have a number and you send a message in my twilio number. Now I want to create a conversation between us.

I need to know what are the steps to handle an incoming message using webhook and create a private channel so that it automatically creates a conversation between the twilio number and the user. I am not able to capture the message in my backend api endpoint which I specified in pre-event and post-event webhook under conversations.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will find the steps required for turning an inbound SMS message into a conversation message in [the documentation on Inbound Message Handling & Autocreation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/inbound-autocreation). All I can do is recommend you read through there.

Comment: Hey Phil, taking a look at the documentation, am I correct that a participant can only be in one conversation at a time. How would we overcome a "customer support"-like feature where one of our agents wants to be talking to multiple customers at the same time. I thought just the consumer phone numbers (customer, and agent) had to be unique?

Comment: That's not correct, you can join multiple channels at the same time.

Comment: Hi Phil, here's a snippet of the response I got on a ticket from Twilio regarding the above, "The number of phone numbers required, is the maximum number of conversations a single participant(participant's phone number) can be in. When a conversation is ended, that frees up that phone number to add the participant into another conversation." The issue is until your business is verified by WhatsApp you can only have 2 numbers, hence two active conversations for an agent. Is this not right?

Comment: The number restriction makes sense, because an agent needs to be addressable by different numbers for different conversations. This is the first you've mentioned of WhatsApp, you can always get more SMS numbers though.

Comment: @SwimmingG in most(if not all) customer support the agents not chatting with SMS, they are using a chat, with a chat you can add each user to lots of conversations, if you want the agent to use sms(not the user), than its right and you need many numbers